# How do I get the input in practice.geektogeek?

Tags: java, input

In the first practice [coding practices first exercise](http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=167) I used `java`

I entered in test input:

```
1
5
1 2 3 2 1
```

Then I just wanted to print what I got in args so in main I do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

but what I get is:

```
[ad6d0e2c0388c211a37a93f12dd4ea078]
```

where is my input? how do I get it?

Comment: You'll have to read it from `stdin` not `args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input in the question aren't command line arguments, but input passed to stdin after the program is run. You can get it from [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), e.g., by using a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```